# Why can't I read values off mgf function?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

In my question I have $M_X(t)= 5/(3-e^t)$, suppose I want to calculate $P(X<3)$.

From the book that I am using, I usually can read off the values of the $M_X(t)$ i.e. if $M_X(t)=1e^t$ then $P(X=1)=1$, however here my $e^t$ is in the denominator position, can someone point me in the right direction here? I have tried rationalizing the fraction but it was not of any use.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use geometric expansion. Notice that $$\frac{5}{3-e^t}=\frac{5}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{3}}=\frac{5}{3}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^k}e^{k\cdot t}.$$
Can you finish?

Comment: do i just expand it out and i am done? sorry i am not familar with such expressions

Comment: i think i got it, thanks!

Comment: So, what are the values that your random variable take? If it takes values 0,1,2,... see that $M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tx}]=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)\cdot e^{t\cdot k}.$ That is what i thought you understand by "read off".

Comment: yes I am actually trying to calculate the values where P ( X<3) . so i guess the values here are 0 ,1 and 2, is that correct? sorry i cant upvote you because i only have < 15 rep

Comment: Yes. No worries. If it satisfies you, you can accept it.